# How to define a more concise scala function

Tags: scala, akka, partialfunction

I am using the akka library and supplying a partial function to be implemented by an actor at runtime via a hot swap.

The akka hot swap takes an argument in the form PartialFunction[Any, Unit].  I have defined mine as the following:

```
class Fake1Reader extends AbstractReader {

  def read: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case readingRequest: ReadingRequest => {
      var reading: Reading = new ReadingImpl(readingRequest.getResourceId, "payload",
        Calendar.getInstance.getTime,
      readingRequest.getfrequency, readingRequest.getMappingName,
        readingRequest.getClassificationType,
      readingRequest.getReadingRequestId)
      sendConsumeMessage(reading)
    }
  }
}
```

so in order to use this function I have to supply a new Fake1Reader().read.

Is there any more concise way of doing this class using apply or extending Function or PartialFunction?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the problem. Could you elaborate/refine?

Comment: You could reduce this by about 30% by calling your variable `r` rather than `readingRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

If your `AbstractReader` is stateless, you can define `object` instead of `class` to avoid unnecessary object creation on every usage,and place your functions there as immutable `val`'s.

Also, companion object `akka.actor.Actor` defines type `Receive` as an alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`, so you can write your partial functions like this:

```
package foo    
object Fake1Reader extends AbstractReader {
  import akka.actor.Actor._

  val read: Receive = { 
    case readingRequest: ReadingRequest => /* implementation */
  }
}
```

usage:

```
import foo.Fake1Reader._

actorRef ! HotSwap(read)
```

Comment: this is for an extremely high concurrency application and I originally had it defined as an object with the single function and switched to class.  I was worried about the singleton thing with many actors accessing the same object.

Comment: Really what I'm looking for is for the class definition to actually be the function, not sure if it's possible.

Comment: If it's immutable/has-no-state then any sharing is not a problem.  If you think you will have a performance problem, it may help to actually have one (or simulate the conditions of one) and then measure the actual overheads.

Comment: You can define a function as a class by extending `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` and implementing `apply` and `isDefinedAt` methods, but I don't think it will help to improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, this reduces the sheer drudgery of repetition:

```
case readingRequest: ReadingRequest => {
  import readingRequest._
  var reading: Reading = new ReadingImpl(getResourceId, "payload",
    Calendar.getInstance.getTime,
  getfrequency, getMappingName,
    getClassificationType,
  getReadingRequestId)
  sendConsumeMessage(reading)
}
```